# Executing a multi-parameter external command to dump ArrangoDB from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, child-process

I am aware there are several ways to deal with shell-executions in Python but I haven't really found the right one for me as it includes the following structure:

```
command [--maincommand.subcommand value]
```

I want to create a backup of a collection from my ArangoDB, using:

```
arangodump  --server.endpoint tcp://qohelet.at:8112  --server.username root  --server.password rootpw  --server.database verstionTestDB  --collection V2  --output-directory 'pyarangoversioning/Tests/10k-node-test/10/backup'  --overwrite true
```

The code looks like the following:

```
def arangoDumpCollection(self, backupcol, outputdict, overwrite=True):

    dumpCollectionString="arangodump "+\
        f" --server.endpoint tcp://{self.server}:{self.port} "+\
        f" --server.username {self.username} "+\
        f" --server.password {self.password} "+\
        f" --server.database {self.database} "+\
        f" --collection {backupcol} "+\
        f" --output-directory '{outputdict}' "

    if overwrite:
        dumpCollectionString+=" --overwrite true"
    
    execute = Popen(dumpCollectionString, shell=True)
```

This here works. But is it done properly? Is there a better way to define the parameters?
I read several posts that would rather advice against a usage of `Popen`.

Should I change this code for something else?

Answer (score 1):

Appending with spaces to a string and calling it with `...(..., shell=True)` is error-prone and [insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess). Consider using a generator to yield the command line arguments and call it with `subprocess.run()`

```py
from subprocess import CompletedProcess, run
from typing import Iterator


def get_arangodump_args(
        self,
        backupcol: str,
        outputdict: str,
        overwrite: bool = True
) -> Iterator[str]:
    """Yield arguments for arangodump."""

    yield '--server.endpoint'
    yield 'tcp://{self.server}:{self.port}'
    yield '--server.username'
    yield self.username
    yield '--server.password'
    yield self.password
    yield '--server.database'
    yield self.database
    yield '--collection'
    yield backupcol
    yield '--output-directory'
    yield outputdict

    if overwrite:
        yield '--overwrite'
        yield 'true'


def run_arango_dump(
        self,
        backupcol: str,
        outputdict: str,
        overwrite: bool = True
) -> CompletedProcess:
    """Invoke the arangodump command."""

    return run(
        [
            'arangodump',
            *self.get_arangodump_args(backupcol, outputdict, overwrite)
        ],
        check=True
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. See the arangodump-reference: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangodump-examples.html - the difference is in this case mainly the different setup of the long string and calling it in a subprocess. What is the advantage over my version except that subprocess is executed instead of Popen?